# real use case of memcpy - and why not taking a simple asignment instead?

Tags: c, memcpy

`memcpy` copies n bytes from the source to the destination. (*linux man page*)

and a simple `assignment` is doing the same, right?

So where are the differences, and what would be a real use case of `memcpy`?

Comment: Assignment doesn't "copy `n` bytes". It assigns values.

Comment: @MatteoItalia missread. :D

Comment: @KerrekSB: Yes, but it very commonly does so by copying `n` bytes.

Comment: Assignments are bound by their fixed size, but you can use `memcpy` with *any* size, even one read from a variable.

Comment: you could simply make a function that has a loop that does a byte by byte assignment... but you have to assume that it would be slower than one of the most optimized calls in any good library..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes and no. Simple assignment will copy values, as you say, so assigning a standard variable, be it a standard data type or a struct, will work fine. The issue typically comes when using arrays. Take the following example:

```
int p,q;
struct myStruct s1, s2;
char str1[50];
char str2[50];
// ...
// Assign stuff to all the variables
// ...
p = q;   // Fine
s1 = s2; // Fine
str1 = str2; // ERROR!
```

For the array cases above, memcpy allows us to copy the data, so to perform `str1 = str2`, we'd actually have to write `memcpy(str1, str2, 50);`

Comment: Unless the language added something since I last used it (admittedly a long time ago), `struct` values can't be assigned directly; you can either copy their contents field by field, or you can use memcpy. (Pointers to structs, like pointers to anything else, can be directly assigned but that's a different operation.)

Comment: @keshlam: Yes, that was added to the language in 1972... :-S ([Demo](http://ideone.com/4SeW69))

Comment: Hm. I don't remember it being supported in the versions I used, but that may simply be a matter of my having originally learned C from K&R and hence never having _tried_ to do struct-to-struct assignment. Now that you mention it, I do seem to remember seeing this mentioned in the ANSI C drafts. Oh well. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Because `memcpy` allows you to copy arrays with just an instruction and because it is typically faster than a hand-made loop (usually it's implemented in highly optimized assembly which copies most of the stuff in chunks as large as machine words).

Answer (score 0):

While you can emulate the function of `memcpy` with simple assignments, `memcpy` will compile usually into a CPU instruction which copies a whole memory area as fast as possible.

You can easily test the difference using an example program:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <memory.h>

const int blockSize = 4096;

void copyA(char *a, char *b)
{
    memcpy(b, a, blockSize);
}

void copyB(char *a, char *b)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < blockSize; ++i) {
        b[i] = a[i];
    }
}

int main()
{
    char *a, *b;
    a = (char*)malloc(blockSize);
    b = (char*)malloc(blockSize);
    memset(a, 0, blockSize);
    memset(b, 1, blockSize);

    for (int i = 0; i < 80000000; ++i) {
        copyA(a, b);
        copyB(a, b);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

If you profile this program you get more or less this result:

[image: Profiler Result]

In simple cases the compiler optimiser detects the simple attempt to "move memory" and automatically replaces the `for` loop with a simple "memory move" instruction.

Compile this example, and check the disassembly generated by the C++ compiler to see the difference.

Add a `printf("%s%s",a,b);` to make sure the compiler doesn't remove everything for optimisation.

Comment: Offtopic for this post, but in C++ you would use `std::copy` for both.